# Flask Logging in ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-logging

I am trying to set up Logging for my Flask app which is deployed in ElasticBeanstalk.

I have a basic logging in place that prints stuff in my console.

But on deploying in Beanstalk, I am not able to see any of the application logs.

Is there any specific config that needs to be setup in order to achieve this?

Just sharing a sample code.

user.py

```
import logging 

class User(Resource): 

    def details(self):
      user_info = "Hello"
      logging.info(user_info)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a config file to your `.ebextensions` folder that adds your application's logs to the logs that EB downloads automatically.

Assuming that your application logs to a folder called `logs` in the Flask app root, you would make a file called `.ebextensions/logging.config` that looks like this:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/your_app_name_logs.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /var/app/current/logs/*.log
```

(Which is a slight variation on the official documents here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html)

Then, after you deploy, you should be able to use the GUI to pull down logs.